# Book about human girl who lives with dragons

Tags: story-identification, books

I read a book ages ago that started off with a pregnant woman dying.  All I remember after that is that she lived with shapeshifting dragons until she was forced to leave, and found more humans.  I vaguely remember something about the humans being magical, but that's about it.  I read this book roughly 14 years ago, but it could well be older than that.

Comment: Just reading the headline made me think of Patricia C. Wrede's Dealing with Dragons, but the rest of the question probably rules that out.

Comment: Rachel Hartman's _Seraphina_ has shapeshifting dragons who pass as human, and a young woman protagonist, but (2012) it's too recent.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[*The Elvenbane*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Halfblood_Chronicles) by Andre Norton and Mercedes Lackey, perhaps?

Comment: YES! That is one of my favorite books, I actually own the trilogy. Ms. Lackey wrote two more with Andre Norton. In order, the Halfblood Chronicles includes: The Elvenbane, Elvenblood, and Elvenborn. I had to wait a long time for that last one...but they finally came out with it and it's pretty good.

Comment: @DawnDeschain Even though the other answer has already been accepted, if you would turn your comment into an answer, it would add valuable information.

Comment: As a caution, the third book ends on a huge cliffhanger and the forth book may or may not ever be released.

Comment: Sorry if I offended. I figured quoting the text from Wikipedia would be helpful for other people to find it.