# An older fantasy book about a primitive girl who lived with dragons

Tags: story-identification, books, dragons

In the 90s I read a 3 book series about a girl who lived with or was close with dragons. They lived in a desert like environment with the dragons having a clan like social structure. The girl had befriended one of the young dragons who was looked poorly upon for having her as a friend or pet. If I remember correctly the girl had wild red hair and the people were described in a primitive way with like leather clothes and spears. The story was a typical coming of age and underdog story. I wish I could remember more details. The cover at the time for the first book may have had a dragon or two fighting with the girl on a rock with a spear? Hope this rings a bell for someone.

Answer (score 5):

Are you perhaps thinking of the [Half-blood Chronicles](https://www.goodreads.com/series/41756-halfblood-chronicles) by Andre Norton and Mercedes Lackey, starting with *[The Elvenbane](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/176892.The_Elvenbane)*, published in 1991?

> This is the story of Shana, a halfbreed born of the forbidden union of an Elvenlord father and a human mother. Her exiled mother dead, she was rescued and raised by dragons, a proud, ancient race who existed unbeknownst to elven or humankind. From birth, Shana was the embodiment of the Prophecy that the all-powerful Elvenlords feared. Her destiny is the enthralling adventure of a lifetime.

Shana is feral, so that would fit the "primitive" aspect of things. The dragon who takes her up is indeed teased about his "pet". I haven't found a cover with a spear, but she is a redhead.

[image: Book cover for *The Elvenbane*]

Comment: @Emily: If this is your book, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.

Comment: And if so, it will be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/27663/book-about-human-girl-who-lives-with-dragons (or I might make that one a dupe of this one due to greater detail).